# Spreadsheets listing all the values that are not blank in the first row of a different sheet down a single column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I've been struggling with this which what to me seems like it shouldn't be this difficult.  I have two checkboxes (Totally different problem) When one is selected I would like to list the nonblank values in the first row of spreadsheet A, but when the other is selected I would like to list the values of spreadsheet B, i realize it will be a simple if statement (If d6 = True,...) and if (g6 = True,...) but I've tried queries which somehow confuse me, I've tried vlookup and can't seem to get the syntax right). Any help would seriously be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(D6=TRUE,IMPORTRANGE("URL of SpreadSheet A","'Sheet Name'!1:1"),IF(G6=TRUE,IMPORTRANGE("URL of SpreadSheet A","'Sheet Name'!1:1"),))),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null",0))
```

Comment: tried changing the code to work with the sheet names in my workbook but I got this error. "Wrong number of arguments to TRANSPOSE. Expected 1 arguments, but got 3 arguments."  I did change the argument in the table box in order to hopefully leave the column range indefinite.  I know you can do this with columns by just using a code like C1:C if you cant do this with rows would you have a work around?

Comment: Sorry, I missed once closing bracket there. Please try again.

Comment: still getting this error "Wrong number of arguments to IMPORTRANGE. Expected 2 arguments, but got 1 arguments."

Comment: There should be no problem with `IMPORTRANGE` in fact (I guess some kind of display bug). Had you linked with the 2 spreadsheets? If not, do so first by using the `IMPORTRANGE` individually

Comment: I actually figured out the problem.  so importrange requires a url, but since im working all within the same workbook id prefer not to have to link via url if possible, i was trying to skip the url and just pull it up by sheetname but thats what was causing the error.

Comment: You told that there are 3 spreadsheets in the question...

Comment: There are 3 spreadsheets but they are all within one googlesheets document.   i would prefer to just reference the spreadsheet by name and not url if possible.  is there another way we can communicate so i can show you what i mean?

Comment: so actually i got it to work without the url but its listing the result horizontally and I need it to go vertically.  Would i just remove a transpose to do that?

Comment: Yah so once i removed the first transpose it seems to be working. Thankyou again!!!

Comment: In such case, it should be '3 sheets in one spreadsheet'.

Answer (score 0):

> When one is selected I would like to list the nonblank values in the first row of spreadsheet A, but when the other is selected I would like to list the values of spreadsheet B, i realize it will be a simple if statement (If d6 = True,...) and if (g6 = True,...)

```
=IF((D6=TRUE)*(G6=FALSE); FILTER(Sheet1!1:1; Sheet1!1:1<>"");
 IF((D6=TRUE)*(G6=TRUE);  FILTER(Sheet2!1:1; Sheet2!1:1<>""); ))
```